# How to separate a JTextField from the rest of the GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, awt, grid-layout

I'm trying to make a calculator as a fun project. But as I try to make it look like a... calculator, it just turns out like one big grid, as follows:

[image: Calculator-Window]

I've tried to follow along with whatever I found on the Internet, but that was a big bust.

Can anyone help me out trying to separate the JTextField so it doesn't do this, and it can be in it's own row?

Here's the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    public Main() {
        // Row = ->
        // Column = ^
        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 0));

        JTextField txtCalc = new JTextField("0");
        txtCalc.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        JButton btn0 = new JButton("0");
        JButton btn1 = new JButton("1");
        JButton btn2 = new JButton("2");
        JButton btn3 = new JButton("3");
        JButton btn4 = new JButton("4");
        JButton btn5 = new JButton("5");
        JButton btn6 = new JButton("6");
        JButton btn7 = new JButton("7");
        JButton btn8 = new JButton("8");
        JButton btn9 = new JButton("9");
        JButton btn10 = new JButton("10");

        cp.add(txtCalc);
        cp.add(btn0);
        cp.add(btn1);
        cp.add(btn2);
        cp.add(btn3);
        cp.add(btn4);
        cp.add(btn5);
        cp.add(btn6);
        cp.add(btn7);
        cp.add(btn8);
        cp.add(btn9);
        cp.add(btn10);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Calculator");
        setSize(600, 600);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Main::new);
    }
}
```

### Edit:

Now I have the answer! This is my fixed code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    public Main() {
        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 0));
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 0));
        setContentPane(border);

        JTextField txtCalc = new JTextField("0");
        txtCalc.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        txtCalc.setEditable(true);

        JButton btn1 = new JButton("1");
        JButton btn2 = new JButton("2");
        JButton btn3 = new JButton("3");
        JButton btn4 = new JButton("4");
        JButton btn5 = new JButton("5");
        JButton btn6 = new JButton("6");
        JButton btn7 = new JButton("7");
        JButton btn8 = new JButton("8");
        JButton btn9 = new JButton("9");
        JButton btn0 = new JButton("0");

        mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(txtCalc, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        buttonPanel.add(btn1);
        buttonPanel.add(btn2);
        buttonPanel.add(btn3);
        buttonPanel.add(btn4);
        buttonPanel.add(btn5);
        buttonPanel.add(btn6);
        buttonPanel.add(btn7);
        buttonPanel.add(btn8);
        buttonPanel.add(btn9);
        buttonPanel.add(btn0);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Main::new);
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for a working example to get you started.

Comment: I did. Like I said, it is hard to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your main panel use a BorderLayout.  Put the JTextField in the North position.  Put your buttons in a panel that uses GridLayout, then add that panel to your main panel in the Center position.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {
public Main() {
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    setContentPane(mainPanel);
    JTextField txtCalc = new JTextField("0");
    txtCalc.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 0));

    JButton btn0 = new JButton("0");
    JButton btn1 = new JButton("1");
    JButton btn2 = new JButton("2");
    JButton btn3 = new JButton("3");
    JButton btn4 = new JButton("4");
    JButton btn5 = new JButton("5");
    JButton btn6 = new JButton("6");
    JButton btn7 = new JButton("7");
    JButton btn8 = new JButton("8");
    JButton btn9 = new JButton("9");

    buttonPanel.add(txtCalc);
    buttonPanel.add(btn0);
    buttonPanel.add(btn1);
    buttonPanel.add(btn2);
    buttonPanel.add(btn3);
    buttonPanel.add(btn4);
    buttonPanel.add(btn5);
    buttonPanel.add(btn6);
    buttonPanel.add(btn7);
    buttonPanel.add(btn8);
    buttonPanel.add(btn9);

    mainPanel.add(txtCalc, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Calculator");
    setSize(600, 600);
    setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Main::new);
}
}
```

Comment: How would I go about doing this?

Comment: `JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); setContentPane(mainPanel); mainPanel.add(txtCalc, BorderLayout.North); JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 0)); mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.Center);`

Comment: Already did that, but when I made a new JPanel and set it to ```new BorderLayout()```, it just makes txtCalc disappear.

Comment: Did you make the mainPanel the content pane? And did you add txtCalc to the mainPanel?

Comment: There! This is much easier to follow! +1

Comment: @JBoyAdvance, updated your original question showing the code you are now using. We can't guess what you are doing.